# tail -f equivalent

Tags: scripting, tail

I am seeing a delay of several seconds with the `tail` command. I found the cause for it has something to do with nfs services. I am using Arch linux and yet to find out how to disable all these services.

I have searched and had some indication that other tools will not be affected such as `cat` so what can give equivalent results to `tail -f`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functionally equivalents to `tail -f` are

```
less +F
```

and where available

```
tailf
```

Comment: Thanks for telling about `less +F`. Seems very helpful when used with `screen`.

Comment: thank,  those are the same results however delay remains. My resolution seems to be to remove nfs

Comment: Also worth mentioning how to stop and start the following - [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81628/is-there-an-alternative-to-tail-f-that-has-convenient-scrolling#81630) sums it up well.

Comment: According to https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/52159 `tailf` is deprecated on arch?

Answer (score 0):

The delay is likely due to buffering of the data.

tail (from the man page) checks for updates every second (changeable with '-s' or '--sleep-interval'), which can cause a perceptible delay.

tailf accesses files without causing a corresponding atime update (access time), which could introduce delays.

And less... as always, less is more!

Answer (score 0):

`tail -F`: same as `-f` with `--retry`. Even better than `tailf` since it works without re-launching the command if the file disappears. Example output:

```
tail: 'some-log-file.log' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: 'some-log-file.log' has appeared;  following new file
```